# Ajax working in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE

Tags: ajax, string, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have the following problem I am working on a big project and I have problem with an ajax call which returns html and in Chrome everything works fine but in Firefox or IE is another story. when I console.log the output chrome outputs the whole html received but the Firefox and IE return just an empty string if anyone has had the same situation I would gladly appriciate the help what could the reason be. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. I'm using Ajax and it always returns error when I try to put `window.location.reload();` statement to Ajax. But without that code it works fine on Firefox. I think the problem is in response. Do you see any response in your browser debug?

Comment: Yes, I do. When I console.log the result it returns an empty variable a.k.a empty string.

Comment: and do you see the status code is 200 for your request, on my request it's not present any code

Comment: Yeah! Maybe you should checking your File want to response again. Some bug make me feel crazy :)). Hope you will figure out the bug.